# Expanding a div based on a floated div

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, html

Second layout question for a CSS newbie.

I have in my ASP.NET layout in the site master page the generated .Main div. I have added a new page called 'Show.aspx' and have added some divs to this. What im trying to do is to expand the '.main' div based on the size of the description div of 'Show.aspx'

To add, I have added the 'description' div on the source server side, where as .main is in the site master CSS page.

Here is the screenshot showing the issue:

[image]

As shown the white .main div is not expanding. I have tried adding overflow:auto but again to no avail. As I am using a float style on my div's after some research this could be the issue but I don't know why.

Code:

sitemaster .main:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>
<body>
<form runat="server">
<div class="page">

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="title">

            <h1>

             <img id="Img1" src = "Images/coffe pic.png" alt="" runat="server" />
                Coffee Stop

                </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="loginDisplay">
        </div>
        <div class="clear hideSkiplink">
            <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Items>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Home"/>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Shop Online" Value="Shop Online"></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Contact Us" Value="Contact Us"></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="About Us" Value="About Us"></asp:MenuItem>
                </Items>
            </asp:Menu>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/>
    </div>
    <div class="clear">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">

</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And my server side added divs of the Show.aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Show.aspx.cs" Inherits="ViewCDs.Show" %>
```

```
   <asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" Height="141px">
       <EditItemTemplate>
           coffeeName:
           <asp:TextBox ID="coffeeNameTextBox" runat="server" 
               Text='<%# Bind("coffeeName") %>' />
           <br />
           coffeeOrigin:
           <asp:TextBox ID="coffeeOriginTextBox" runat="server" 
               Text='<%# Bind("coffeeOrigin") %>' />
           <br />
           coffeeStrength:
           <asp:TextBox ID="coffeeStrengthTextBox" runat="server" 
               Text='<%# Bind("coffeeStrength") %>' />
           <br />
           coffeeGrind:
           <asp:TextBox ID="coffeeGrindTextBox" runat="server" 
               Text='<%# Bind("coffeeGrind") %>' />
           <br />
           coffeePrice:
           <asp:TextBox ID="coffeePriceTextBox" runat="server" 
               Text='<%# Bind("coffeePrice") %>' />
           <br />
           coffeeQty:
           <asp:TextBox ID="coffeeQtyTextBox" runat="server" 
               Text='<%# Bind("coffeeQty") %>' />
           <br />
           coffeeRRP:
           <asp:TextBox ID="coffeeRRPTextBox" runat="server" 
               Text='<%# Bind("coffeeRRP") %>' />
           <br />
           <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" 
               CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
           &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateCancelButton" runat="server" 
               CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
       </EditItemTemplate>
       <InsertItemTemplate>
           coffeeName:
           <asp:TextBox ID="coffeeNameTextBox" runat="server" 
               Text='<%# Bind("coffeeName") %>' />
           <br />
           coffeeOrigin:
           <asp:TextBox ID="coffeeOriginTextBox" runat="server" 
               Text='<%# Bind("coffeeOrigin") %>' />
           <br />
           coffeeStrength:
           <asp:TextBox ID="coffeeStrengthTextBox" runat="server" 
               Text='<%# Bind("coffeeStrength") %>' />
           <br />
           coffeeGrind:
           <asp:TextBox ID="coffeeGrindTextBox" runat="server" 
               Text='<%# Bind("coffeeGrind") %>' />
           <br />
           coffeePrice:
           <asp:TextBox ID="coffeePriceTextBox" runat="server" 
               Text='<%# Bind("coffeePrice") %>' />
           <br />
           coffeeQty:
           <asp:TextBox ID="coffeeQtyTextBox" runat="server" 
               Text='<%# Bind("coffeeQty") %>' />
           <br />
           coffeeRRP:
           <asp:TextBox ID="coffeeRRPTextBox" runat="server" 
               Text='<%# Bind("coffeeRRP") %>' />
           <br />
           <asp:LinkButton ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" 
               CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" />
           &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="InsertCancelButton" runat="server" 
               CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
       </InsertItemTemplate>
       <ItemTemplate>

           <b>Origin:</b>
           <asp:Label ID="coffeeOriginLabel" runat="server" 
               Text='<%# Bind("coffeeOrigin") %>' />
           <br />

           <b>Grind:</b>
           <asp:Label ID="coffeeGrindLabel" runat="server" 
               Text='<%# Bind("coffeeGrind") %>' />
           <br />

           <b>Price: £</b>
           <asp:Label ID="coffeePriceLabel" runat="server" 
               Text='<%# Bind("coffeePrice") %>' />
           <br />

               <b>Strength:</b>
           <asp:Label ID="coffeeStrengthLabel" runat="server" 
               Text='<%# Bind("coffeeStrength") %>' />
           <br />

           <b>Stock Level:</b>
           <asp:Label ID="coffeeQtyLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("coffeeQty") %>' />
           <br />


       </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:FormView>
   <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
       ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CoffeeConnectionString %>" 
       SelectCommand="SELECT [coffeeName], [coffeeOrigin], [coffeeStrength], [coffeeGrind], [coffeePrice], [coffeeQty], [coffeeRRP] FROM [Coffees]">
   </asp:SqlDataSource>

   <br />
```

Beans
        Smooth
        Course

```
  <div style=" float:left; width: 165px; height: 40px;">
  <br />
      <b><asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Quantity:"></asp:Label></b>
 </div>

  <div style=" float:right; width: 165px; height: 40px;">
   <br />

      <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="40px">1</asp:TextBox>

 </div>
     <div style=" float:left; width: 165px; height: 40px;">
     <br />

         <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Buy" />

 </div>

 <div>

</div>
</div>

<br />
<br />

<div id = "titleDescrip" style="position:absolute; top:445px; font-size:20pt;" runat="server" > 

</div> 

<div id="divDescrip" style="position:absolute; top:480px; width:925px;" runat="server"> 

</div>

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: doesnt %100 height work?

Comment: @btevfik  Many thanks for your reply, Sadly adding height:100% to the ,main in the master CSS dosent work.

Comment: Do you need to position your inner `div`s absolutely? Doing so removes them from the document flow, so your `.main` div won't expand to contain them, as you're seeing.

Comment: @ultranaut im absolute purely so I can posistion the divs where you see them. If there is a better way to do it i would be grateful for your help

Comment: It's kind of hard to say without knowing what the rest of the structure is like, for instance what is the `445px` you're leaving at the top accounting for, and is it something that's contained in `.main` or is it outside of it? Are you using absolute positioning on those divs in order to work around other absolutely positioned divs? etc. If you could set up a fiddle or provide enough html/css to reproduce the situation, that'd help.

Comment: @ultranaut I have added the whole of both of the classes to my question. the 445px posistions it from the top left cornerdown to the posistion under the image it is at now. It is purely contained in the show.aspx class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see there are few things you need to understand.

Master Page and Child page both get combined to become one, at runtime.

by that what I mean is suppose you have below container in your Master Page

```
<div class="main">
     <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="mainContent" runat="server">
     </asp:ContentPlaceHolder">
</div>
```

and in your child page, viz `Show.aspx`, you have your containers like

```
   <asp:Content id="mains" ContentPlaceHolderId="mainContent">
         <div class="pagecontent">
         </div>
         <div class="description">
         </div> 
   </asp:Content>
```

then at runtime they get rendered something like this(ofcours there are some more containers):

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="pagecontent">
    </div>
    <div class="description">
    </div>
</div>
```

Secondly, you are using `position:absolute` for your inner elements, don't do that.

when you do `position:absolute`, you remove that element from the documents normal flow, so now, loosely speaking, the parent div, doesn't care what the dimensions of its absolute positioned children are!!

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manishmishra121/ECBhW/).

No matter what height you give to the inner divs, the main always expand accordingly, because main has no height defined, hence its height:auto

Comment: Many thanks and a great answer. A couple of questions if i may. Does the ID of the contentPlaceHolder have to be the same for both parent and child classes? I.e Both of the classes have the ID of 'mainContent' In my code the master has the ID of 'headContant' and Show.aspx has the ID 'mainContent'.

Comment: two things are here, ASP:ContentPlaceHolder and ASP:Content. former one is defined inside Master page and later one is defined inside Child Pages. Former one can have any 'Id' and later one can also have any 'Id'. whatever you want. But later one should have 'ContentPlaceHolderId' from one of the former ones 'Id's!.

Comment: Mashra Many thanks again its ok i kind of answered my own question when changing the code around of the fact the id's make no difference. I have been onto the fiddle but still cant see what would be the best style option to posistion the divs.

Comment: check my fiddle now. you can play around with divs very easily

Answer (score 0):

try

```
.main

{

display:table-column;
padding: 0px 12px;
margin: 12px 8px 8px 8px;
min-height: 420px;

}
```

and add display:block; to child class